# AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'player1'

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, oop

I was try to make a game in Python using class where I stumbled upon this error. The code of the game Engine is:

```
class Engine(object):
players = {"Arjuna":Arjuna("Shivam")}
def __init__(self):
    return

def seek_player(self,input):
    player1 = self.players.get(input)
    player2 = Player("Shivam")
    self.attack(player1, player2)
    return player1, player2

def attack(self, player1, player2):
    attack = raw_input("Choose your attack: ")
    chosen_one = self.player1.moves.get(attack)
    print "Your attack power is", chosen_one
    new_health = self.player2.health() - chosen_one
    print new_health
    return

a = Engine()
input = raw_input("Choose your player: ")
a.seek_player(input)
```

I do this and after steps get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class.py", line 62, in <module>
    a.seek_player(input)
  File "class.py", line 49, in seek_player
    self.attack(player1, player2)
  File "class.py", line 54, in attack
    chosen_one = self.player1.moves.get(attack)
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'player1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access self.player1 because you never initiated it. You only initiated player. Change your seek_player method to

```
def seek_player(self,input):
    self.player1 = self.players.get(input)
    self.player2 = Player("Shivam")
    self.attack(self.player1, self.player2)
    return self.player1, self.player2
```

Note: It is good practice to initiate Class variables in init method, you might consider adding

```
self.player1 = None
self.player2 = None
```

To your **init**() method

Comment: Now I am getting this
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class.py", line 64, in <module>
    a.seek_player(input)
  File "class.py", line 51, in seek_player
    self.attack(player1, player2)
NameError: global name 'player1' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, I missed those variables in my example, it is now edited. You need to change arguments from self.attack(player1, player2) to self.attack(self.player1, self.player2). You must understand that once you initiate Class variable (i.e.: self.player1) you can access it anywhere in your class but you must use keyword "self" that represents instance of Class.
Also you probably do not need to return variables player1 and player2.

Comment: Sorry to sound foolish but I already tried that getting another error.

Comment: `File "class.py", line 56, in attack
    chosen_one = self.player1.moves.get(attack)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: It seems like you didnt show us your whole code. Is there somewhere class Player ? You seems to initiate self.player2 as instance of class Player. I'm going to assume that in __init__() it takes argument name, in case of self.player2 that would be "Shivam". If so, than you probably meant to initiate player1 as self.player1 = Player(input)

Comment: Yes I have a Player class.

Comment: No I did not want to initiate player1 as an instace of Player. I wanted to take an input from user, search a dict using the input as key and set player1 as an instance of that defined class

Comment: Oh, in that case (assuming self.player1 is instance of Arjuna class) is quite clear, your function "moves" (In Arjuna class) does not have "get" attribute. Again I advise you to edit your original question and add more of your code that is relevant to this problem (In this case Arjuna class)

Comment: Oh sorry I got the error. The compiler was confusing between moves function and moves dict. Thank you by the way.